# The difference between an AWS service and product.

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm looking for a list of all the AWS products and their pricing information and I came across the [Bulk API offer index file](https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/index.json). This file contain the links for AWS services pricing info (such as [SNS](http:///https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonSNS/current/index.json)). However this file contain many products. I don't understand the difference between a service and a product, shouldn't be for each service only one product ?

Comment: Can you give us an example or two of a 'product' that you are seeing?

Comment: The SNS service for example, when I go to the linked file I find Message delivery and data transfer are listed as products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, a *service* is an AWS service, like SNS, SQS, S3, etc.  The *products* represent each individual usage and billing component associated with that service, such as (in the case of SNS) various types of message delivery events (per event), or outbound/inbound data transfer (per GB).

Note that billing components are defined for each individual product.  When there is no charge for a particular product -- such as is sometimes the case for certain classes of data transfer -- there is still a billing component, but it happens to be priced as $0.00 per unit.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. However I have another question relating to the same files. The services listed on the index file are less than those presented in the AWS web page. For instance the IoT class have 6 services under it while the file have only 1 IoT service. This confused me because I assumed  I'll find direct mapping between pricing and services. Question is why they are not the same.

Comment: I'm sure there's an explanation, but I'll have to take a look.